# Type for 2 objects with same key and a key

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts 2 objects and a key which is one of the keys of the object.

**Key should be same but value TYPE can be different**

Example:

```
obj1 = {name: null, salary: 10000, age: 20};
obj2 = {name: 'tam', salary: '300040', age: 50};
key = 'name' // key can be either 'name', 'salary', or 'age'
```

All keys or obj1 and obj2 must be same.
Key must be one of the keys in object.

I tried to build type like this:

```
 sortComparator?:<T, K extends keyof T>(
    row1: T,
    row2: T,
    accessor: K
  )
```

This did not work because name can be null or string. We do not know the object type before hand.

Comment: Why so many generic parameters? What's wrong with just something along the lines of `function sortComparator<T>(row1: T, row2: T, accessor: keyof T) {};`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzQQrm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you jcalz.
In this solution, typescript doesn't complain if obj1 and obj2 have different keys.
Example:

const obj1 = { name: null, salary: 10000, age: 20, someOtherKey: 3 };
const obj2 = { name: 'tam', salary: '300040', age: 50 };

Comment: Why do you care if they have different keys, as long as the one you're comparing exists on both?  You can never be sure that two objects have the same keys since objects may have keys TypeScript doesn't know about.  Can you [edit] to demonstrate an actual problem that arises in this case?  I can try to harden the comparator against known keys that don't match as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxqq1W), but it's more complicated so I'd like to see a demonstration of why someone should bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve type safety for your sortComparator function and ensure that row1 and row2 have the same keys, you can use TypeScript's generic types and mapped types. Here's a possible type definition for your sortComparator:

```
type SortComparator<T, K extends keyof T> = (row1: T, row2: T, accessor: K) => number;
```

Comment: Wow, this works, however it doesn't work if the value type is different between 2 rows.

obj1 = {name: null, salary: '10000', age: 20};
obj2 = {name: 'tam', salary: '30000', age: 50};

here it complains that `name` value type is different.

Comment: you can modify it as per your data and requirements. just play with it :) happy coding